# Pressing ctrl+t doesn't work in Selenium Webdriver using ActionChains

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to open a new browser tab in my test and I've read that the best approach is to simply send the appropriate keys to the browser. I'm using windows so I use `ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "t").perform()`, however, this does nothing.

I tried the following to test that `Keys.CONTROL` is working properly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def test_trial():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v").perform()
```

This indeed passes whatever I have copied in the clipboard to the Google search box that is in focus by default.

This is what I want to use but that is not working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def test_trial():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "t").perform()
```

Nothing seems to happen to the browser, no new tab opened, no dialog box, no notification. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this java Script Executor it should work.

```
link="https://www.google.com"
driver.execute_script("window.open('{}');".format(link))
```

`Edited` code with window handle.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

link="https://www.google.com"
driver.execute_script("window.open('{}');".format(link))
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("test")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
Could I also ask how to get focus of this new window? It is created and the browser switches to it but all the commands I send through webdriver seem to be executed in the original window.

Comment: Try window handle.

Comment: I switch to the new window now but when trying to interact with the elements I get: `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: The `switch_to.window` method works fine (I tried switching to `window_before`) but when I try to click on an element in the new window I still get the same error

Comment: @CrispJam: I have tested then posted here.

Comment: Yes you are right, your example works fine. There must be an issue in how I transfer this to the actual app I'm testing. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try executing this script:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com');")
```

for example

```
myURL = 'https://www.google.com'
driver.execute_script("window.open('" + myURL + "');")
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed my issue, thank you! Could you please link me towards documentation on this? I've never seen this `execute_script` method being used and would like to know more about how it works.

Comment: @CrispJam `execute_script` executes any javascript via `WebDriver`. You can read about it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference! A follow up question: can I pass the URL in a variable instead of a string literal? For example doing: `driver.execute_script("window.open(myURL);")`

Comment: @Nihal what you suggest in the edit does not seem to work for me. I have this now: `driver.execute_script("window.open(" + address[0] + ");")` and I get the following error: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 0):

You’ve gotten some good answers utilizing JavaScript execution, but I am curious why your example doesn’t work in the first place.

It’s possible that your ActionChains line is executed before the page has fully loaded; you could try adding a wait as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def test_trial():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(By.TAG_NAME("body")))
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "t").perform()
```